# Ws Federation in ASP .NET MVC CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use the asp .net MVC core 2.1 to config ws federation, but when localhost config runs smoothly, but when using from another computer on LAN or global network, it redirects to localhost URL then can't respond, how to fix it?

I used url from IP address, then it'll direct to localhost url

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: I am new in that. If you need more information Please refer this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @SunilDhappadhule yes, I did like that link, but it only works on localhost

Answer (score 0):

[I'm config in Startup file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZt8e.png)

It'll run on localhost, but when I access from another machine through IP address, it can't direct to IP address request, it direct to localhost like wtrealm config